# Getting null value instead of input value in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, intellij-idea, dart-null-safety

I am receiving a null value when I am saving a value as in my code I have three fields

```
   String? _itemName ="";
   String? _dateCreated ="";
   int? _id;
```

and when after running my project, I insert an item by calling this method:

```
Future<int> saveItem(NoDoItem item) async
{
    var dbClient = await database;
    int res = await dbClient.insert(tableName, item.toMap());
    debugPrint(res.toString());
    return res;
}
```

Using `saveItem()` function:

```
void _hndleSubmitted(String text) async
  {
      _textEditingController.clear();

      NoDoItem noDoItem = NoDoItem(text, DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
      int savedItemId = await db.saveItem(noDoItem);

      debugPrint("Item saved ID: $savedItemId");
 }
```

and after this when I am retrieving all `itemNames`, I get null value instead of user entered value

Defining `getItems()` func:

```
Future<List> getItems() async
{
    var dbClient = await database;
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY $columnItemName ASC");
    return result.toList();
}
```

Using `getItems()` function:

```
 _readNotoDoItems() async
  {
    List items = await db.getItems();
    items.forEach((item) {
      NoDoItem noDoItem = NoDoItem.map(item);
      print("Db items:  ${noDoItem.itemName}");
    });
  }
```

Please tell me what is the the reason that I am getting a null value instead of entered value and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check what is in your database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null value is saving instead of entered value in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541212/null-value-is-saving-instead-of-entered-value-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
void _hndleSubmitted(String text) async {
    _textEditingController.clear(); // <--------- HERE

      NoDoItem noDoItem = NoDoItem(text, DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
      int savedItemId = await db.saveItem(noDoItem);

      debugPrint("Item saved ID: $savedItemId");
 }
```

you clear the value with `_textEditingController.clear();` right before using it. move it after adding the item to database

```
void _hndleSubmitted(String text) async {
     NoDoItem noDoItem = NoDoItem(text, DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
     int savedItemId = await db.saveItem(noDoItem);
     textEditingController.clear();
     debugPrint("Item saved ID: $savedItemId");
  }
```

Comment: No it is not working bro